# Scan values from a macro variable and store it in a column in data set using SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
%let abc = ("234.34", "C56.67", "2345.67", "C67.56") ;
```

**Output:**
Table1

**Col1**

234.34

C56.67

2345.67

C67.56

This is throwing an error, can somebody please guide me:

```
%macro generate ;


    %local i ;

    data table1;

    length Col1 $100.;

    %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&abc.));

          Col1 = %scan(&abc., &i.,,"sq");
          output;

     %end;
    run;

%mend;

%generate;
```

Comment: Why are you using a macro loop and not a data step loop? Try that instead, it'll work fine.

Comment: Did you try `%scan(%superq(abc), &I, %str(,)) `?

Comment: I tried using below code, it is also not working

data table1;

length Col1 $100.;

do i=1 to %sysfunc(countw(&abc.));
Col1 = %scan(&abc., &i.,,"sq");
output;

end;
run;

Comment: Or maybe, `create table tab1 (col1 varchar(32)); insert into tab1 values (%scan(%superq(abc), &i, %str(,))) ;` create the blank table first and keep inserting your values with a do while loop.

Comment: Do you have any control over how ABC is set or created? Do you have to have the brackets/quotes/commas? If you simplify that, the problem is trivial

Comment: That is the problem,
I am getting ABC as a standard macro from a process, I cannot change that

Comment: If you're feeding a macro var with `separated by ',' ` then you shouldn't be getting any errors with a datastep loop with scan, or a macro block do while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `DO` loop, but you will need to remove the `()` from the value of the macro variable.

```
%let abc = ("234.34", "C56.67", "2345.67", "C67.56") ;
data table1;
  length Col1 $100.;
  do Col1 = %substr(&abc,2,%length(&abc)-2);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

If the values do not contain `()` then you could also just use `%scan(&abc,1,())`, which also has the advantage of working whether or not the original value has the enclosing `()`.

Or just remove the `()` from the value and add them back when you use the macro variable in place where they are needed.

```
%let abc = "234.34", "C56.67", "2345.67", "C67.56" ;
...
  do Col1 = &abc ;
...
  where dxcode in (&abc) 
....
```

Answer (score 2):

you do not need a macro and one way to do this.

```
%let abc = ("234.34", "C56.67", "2345.67", "C67.56" );
%let abc = %qsysfunc(compress(&abc,%str(%"%)%()));
data table1;
length Col1 $100.;
do i = 1 to countw("&abc", ","); 
Col1 = scan("&abc", i,','); 
output; 
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

A proc sql way

`%let abc = ("234.34", "C56.67", "2345.67", "C67.56") ;`

```
proc sql;
create table tab1 (col1 varchar(100));
quit;

options macrogen mlogic;

%macro gen;
%let i = 1;
%do %while (%scan(%superq(abc),&i,%str(,)) ne %str( ));

proc sql;
insert into tab1
values(%scan(%superq(abc),&i,%str(,)));
quit;

%let i = %sysevalf(&i + 1);
%end;

%mend gen; %gen;
```

It would scan through your macro that is delimited by `","`, and progress by 1 with each loop.